# RDKit Build errors

Tags: ubuntu, build, path, open-source, rdkit

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and tried installing the RDKit from the [official documentation](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html#building-the-rdkit). 
I installed the pre-requisites, downloaded the zip file and extracted it to my folder. Made a build directory, entered it and I entered `cmake ..` and this was the output

```
    -- Found Catch2 source in /home/krishna/Coding/GitHub Projects/rdkit-Release_2018_09_1/External/catch/catch
CATCH: /home/krishna/Coding/GitHub Projects/rdkit-Release_2018_09_1/External/catch/catch/single_include
CMake Warning at /home/krishna/anaconda3/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1727 (message):
  No header defined for python-py37; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:236 (find_package)


PYTHON Py_ENABLE_SHARED: 0
PYTHON USING LINK LINE: -pthread -shared -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-rpath,/home/krishna/anaconda3/lib -L/home/krishna/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-rpath,/home/krishna/anaconda3/lib -L/home/krishna/anaconda3/lib
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   serialization
== Using strict rotor definition
-- Found MAEParser source in /home/krishna/Coding/GitHub Projects/rdkit-Release_2018_09_1/External/CoordGen/maeparser
-- Found coordgenlibs source in /home/krishna/Coding/GitHub Projects/rdkit-Release_2018_09_1/External/CoordGen/coordgenlibs
== Updating Filters.cpp from pains file
== Done updating pains files
-- Found RapidJSON source in /home/krishna/Coding/GitHub Projects/rdkit-Release_2018_09_1/External
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/krishna/Coding/GitHub Projects/rdkit-Release_2018_09_1/build
```

Later when i entered `make` I receive the following

```
[  0%] Built target catch
[  0%] Built target inchi_support
[  0%] Building CXX object External/CoordGen/CMakeFiles/maeparser.dir/maeparser/MaeBlock.cpp.o
In file included from /home/krishna/Coding/GitHub Projects/rdkit-Release_2018_09_1/External/CoordGen/maeparser/MaeBlock.cpp:1:0:
/home/krishna/Coding/GitHub Projects/rdkit-Release_2018_09_1/External/CoordGen/maeparser/MaeBlock.hpp:3:10: fatal error: boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
External/CoordGen/CMakeFiles/maeparser.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target 'External/CoordGen/CMakeFiles/maeparser.dir/maeparser/MaeBlock.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [External/CoordGen/CMakeFiles/maeparser.dir/maeparser/MaeBlock.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:275: recipe for target 'External/CoordGen/CMakeFiles/maeparser.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [External/CoordGen/CMakeFiles/maeparser.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have installed the latest boost library, the bashrc file also has been updated to

```
export RDBASE=/rdkit-Release_2018_09_1/Release_2018_09_1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$RDBASE/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$RDBASE:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$PATH:/Coding/boost_1_69_0
```

Please help! What should be changed to successfully build the module?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment (reputation...) but I see you are using Anaconda. Why don't you install via conda? Just type `conda install rdkit` in the environment for which you want to install rdkit.

Comment: It can be an answer

Comment: Based on the question, the library involves C++ dependencies, which likely means OP has a system without a pre-built version of the module, making this option trigger building and lead back to square one.